# Paths searched for ViewComponent files in RazorPages app?

Tags: razor-pages

.NET Core 3.0 Razorpages app

**ViewComponents** folder
- My viewcomponent class is here.  Derives from ViewComponent and returns

```
return await Task.FromResult((IViewComponentResult)View("Default"));
```

**Pages/Components/MyViewComponent**
- Detault.chtml, this is the view template to be used by my viewcomponent

I have a breakpoint set within InvokeAsync where I am trying to return the view and thats when I get the 404

Are the path locations right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Pages/Components/MyViewComponent
>   - Detault.html, this is the view template to be used by my viewcomponent

The view part of a ViewComponent should be a Razor file, not a plain html file. It should be Default.**cshtml**.

Ref: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/view-components

Comment: Sorry, my bad I typed it wrong in the post, but I am infact using default.cshtml